# How to access an object with a hash character in the key name?

Tags: php, json, object

How do you access a PHP object that has a `#` in the $key name?

Example:

```
[image] => stdClass Object 
       ( 
       [#text] => http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/85003/Red+Hot+Chili+Peppers.jpg 
       [name] => original 
       [width] => 937 
       [height] => 1276 
       )
```

I want to access the `#text` property, but `$image->#text` doesn't work because PHP interprets the `#` as the start of a comment.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$image->{'#text'}
```

Comment: Great! I have to wait 4 minutes to accept, but this is perfect (and bloody quick). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

maybe like this: (not sure)

```
$image->{"#text"}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use variable key names:

```
$keyname = '#text';
$value = $image->$keyname;
```